# How to trade Power between Cities?

Tags: simcity-4

I just started with this quite old game. I have a rather good working city and wanted to export garbage to the neighbouring city. This worked fine. Then I wanted to import Electricity from the neighbouring city. This didn't work at all.

Here's what I did:
Build a road to the edge. Build a power line to the edge. Go to the other city, built three power plants and give them full money and build garbage places, connect everything with streets and lines. Go back to the main city. I can export garbage. Fine. But I can not import Power. Not fine.

My city went to ruin because I had no money left and I destroyed the power plants because I thought that importing only works when I have no power plants.

Can someone please give me a detailed explanation on how to trade electricity between cities?

Comment: I hope that you backup your city before destroying the power plant.

Comment: I submitted an edit to Samyam's answer. BuyerCity must have enough cash on hand, and BuyerCity must have a power shortage (or perhaps only a small surplus).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets call the city that buys Power as BuyerCity and the city that Sells power as seller City.
Here are the things to note before initiating a power deal.

1. Make sure BuyerCity  and SellerCity are neighbours!
2. Build Power plants in SellerCity.
3. Build power lines to SimNation(edge of map towards the buyer city) in SellerCity.
4. In BuyerCity you should see some power lines towards edge of map to SellerCity.(Do not demolish these. This represents the connection to the other city.)
5. BuyerCity must have enough cash on hand to pay for the power. (Possibly need enough cash to fund the deal for a year)
6. BuyerCity must need power. Check the power graph. (Possibly has a deficit or a surplus of less than 1000 MW)
7. Go to budget panel and click on it to get budget overview. Here you can now initiate a power deal with the SellerCity by clicking on Neighbour Deals(In the reds section).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. It did not work. Are there any other requirements to be met (like population, amount of power that is "missing", ...)?

Comment: I edited step 4 in my post. Make sure your connecting lines coming from seller city are intact. Do not delete these. Make sure the power plants from seller city have surplus power before you save and exit to region map.

Comment: Of course I connected the lines from the seller city to my buyer city. Still, it does not work.

Comment: I heard someone say you need at least 1000 surplus power in the seller city helps.

Answer (score 1):

To make the initial deal, there can't be other sources of power in the buying city. So if you've built a windmill, for example, you'll have to bulldoze it before a deal can be made. After the deal starts, rebuild your windmill. I only had to do this on the first buy, later ones with the windmill present worked fine.

Comment: I seriously don't believe it is necessary for the supply of power, water or garbage in one city to be *zero* before it is allowed to buy from neighbouring cities.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the buying city must not have any energy producers that have the boxed checked - sell power to region. Once all power producers in the buying city have that unchecked then the city started to import energy.

Answer (score -3):

Are the cross border power lines connected to the power plants on the seller city AMD connected to a zoned area in your buyer city, if no then no deal will be initiated.